# Why is this example (non-simplicial $\mathbb R$-tree) not a simplicial complex?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, simplicial-complex

This is an example of a non-simplicial $\mathbb R$-tree (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_tree)): Start with the interval $[0,2]$, for each positive integer $n$, glue an interval of length $1$ to the point $1-1/n$ in the original interval. The set of singular points (points whose complement has three or more connected components) is discrete, but fails to be closed since $1$ is an ordinary point in this $\mathbb R$-tree. So gluing an interval to $1$ would result in a closed set of singular points which makes the set of singular points non-discrete. (We call this construction $X$).

And a real tree $T$ is simplicial if and only if the set of singular points of $T$ is discrete in $X$. So the example above is not a simplicial complex.

But $X$ is the set of simplices satisfying (1) every face of a simplex is also in $X$ (trivially true); (2) the non-empty intersection of any simplifies is a face of both of them (trivially true). So isn’t $X$ a simplicial complex from the definition? I wonder where I made wrong to get this contradiction?

Comment: I think the description in the Wikipedia is imprecise: the topological gluing doesn't tell you what the metric is. I think the example should be carried out by gluing on vertical intervals to the $x$-axis in the plane. Then you get a tree where the vertex set does not carry the discrete topology, as it ought to in a a simplicial tree.

Comment: When you say "is" simplicial complex, you really mean "is homeomorphic" to a simplicial complex. Try to construct a simplicial complex rigorously using the definition of a simplicial complex (what you wrote in your question is not even close!) and then try to construct a homeomorphism to the space described in your example $X$. Then you will see where your mistake is.

Comment: On reflection, the Wikipedia authors probably mean you to use the path-length metric and then what they say about singular points make sense. (And a variant of the argument in my above comment also works, the set of leaves of the tree has an accumulation point, which should not happen in a simplicial tree.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan the definition I am using for simplicial complex is from p.7 of Munkres's Elements of algebraic topology. If you think it's "not even close", please give your definition. I don't see my mistake, could you please be more precise.

Comment: @Danny In order to define a simplicial complex you have to describe the set of simplices and the face-maps between them. You did not do either one of these things

Comment: Regarding your mistake, the definition of simplicial complex in Munkres is a topology definition, and the topology is specifically described; let me refer to this as the simplicial topology. The object in your post is a certain subset of the Euclidean plane. Assuming you can clear up the mistake identified in the previous comment of @MoisheKohan, then there are further mistakes to clear up: Have you checked whether the topology on your subset is the simplicial topology? Have you even specified the topology on your subset?